# Как понять код в NgModelController?

Tags: angularjs

В функции $$parseAndValidate() есть такая проверка

```
if (isNumber(ctrl.$modelValue) && isNaN(ctrl.$modelValue)) {
  // ctrl.$modelValue has not been touched yet...
  ctrl.$modelValue = ngModelGet($scope);
}
```

В каких случаях условие срабатывает? Что это за странная проверка?
[исходный код на GiHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L721)

Comment: что за функция `$$parseAndValidate()`? откуда выдран данный код? какая из трех операций производимых в коде непонятна?

Comment: я же написал  - код в функции контроллера NgModelController. 
**ctrl.$modelValue** содержит значение инпута. Меня интересует при каких условиях сработает if-часть **(isNumber(ctrl.$modelValue) && isNaN(ctrl.$modelValue))**
Получается идёт проверка значения одновременно на isNumber и на isNaN.

Comment: Стоит добавить ссылку на место где вы это увидели. очевидно `if` сработает когда значение равно `NaN`

Comment: ссылку указал в вопросе

Comment: на строку которая приведена в вопросе

Comment: Добавил в вопросе номер строки, где находится данная проверка

Comment: А зачем вообще полезли настолько внутрь?

Comment: из любопытства. а так - да. понял в чём прикол. Как вы и написали - isNumber возвращает true, если аргумент NaN.

Comment: Нет, суть проверки другая - она выполнится _только_ если у `ctrl.$modelValue` значение `NaN`, если у нее будет какое-то не числовое значение - то уже в `if` не войдет. Если обратили внимание в начале определения контроллера этому полю присваивается `NaN` таким образом определяют, что еще ни разу этому полю не присваивалось реальное значение модели

Comment: ага. точно. а то я думал нафигам они NaN им назначили? Интересный подход.